# Installing mfpmigrate-cli via npm 404 errors

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-cli

When trying to install mfpmigrate-cli using npm v3.10.10 and node v6.11.4 I receive the following errors:

```
npm ERR! fetch failed http://visustar.francelab.fr.ibm.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/mobile-npm-all/mockery/-/mockery-1.7.0.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed http://visustar.francelab.fr.ibm.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/mobile-npm-all/readdir-recursive/-/readdir-recursive-0.0.4.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed http://visustar.francelab.fr.ibm.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/mobile-npm-all/brace-expansion/-/brace-expansion-1.1.8.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed http://visustar.francelab.fr.ibm.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/mobile-npm-all/rimraf/-/rimraf-2.6.2.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed http://visustar.francelab.fr.ibm.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/mobile-npm-all/grunt-legacy-log/-/grunt-legacy-log-0.1.3.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed http://visustar.francelab.fr.ibm.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/mobile-npm-all/jshint-stylish/-/jshint-stylish-1.0.2.tgz
npm ERR! Darwin 17.0.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "mfpmigrate-cli"
npm ERR! node v6.11.4
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10

npm ERR! fetch failed with status code 404
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/e111128/npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jeff, there is an issue with the latest mfpmigrate-cli that is leading to this issue.  Please try the following to install the earlier version:

npm install -g mfpmigrate-cli@8.0.20170615055734

There is an APAR that is open that is related to this issue:  PI96509.

Thanks.  Tom.